# Redirect service requests to another server

Tags: http, grails, http-redirect

I've created a filter so that I can intercept all controller actions and forward the request to a different server.
I need to temporarily redirect based on user-agent.

So I have the following in http://www.mysite1.com

```
class DealsFilters {

    def filters = {
    all(controller: '*', action: '*') {
        before = {
                if (someConditionHere)
                {
                    redirect(url:"http://www.mysite2/")
                    return
                }               
        }
    }       
}
```

What I am wondering is will the request and all it params be correctly passed to mysite2? 

 i.e. mysite1 acts as a service and receives requests to get user data, update deals, add new users, etc...

mysite2 is a new version of mysite1 (mysite1 will be decommisioned after mysite2 has been tested).

Is it as simple as a redirect?

Thanks

Comment: Are there some reasons impeding you to write a simple 301 redirect on your virtual host configuration? It would be better, avoiding such additional and specific code.

Comment: @lucke - Well I need to to extract the user-agent from the request and redirect if it's contains a certain string i.e. the mobile device application version. Not sure is this possible in virtual host config?

Comment: gotcha and I don't think it's possible in virtual host config AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using grails 1.3.7 as pointed out to lucke84 (I should have stated this in original question).

Found following link gave me most of the answer:
[Best practice for redirecting from one web domain to another in Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077313/best-practice-for-redirecting-from-one-web-domain-to-another-in-grails)

```
redirect(url:"http://localhost:8080${request.forwardURI}?${request.queryString}",params:params)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) says that if you perform a redirect with the url parameter, your url should contain all the information needed to send the new request.

I guess you should recreate your url, more or less like this:

```
redirect(base: 'http://www.mysite2/', controller: params.controller, action: params.action, params: params)
```

Not tested, but it should work for most of the cases. Let me know :)

Comment: I'm actually using grails 1.3.7.
http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Controllers/redirect.html
will url work?

Comment: redirect(url: 'http://www.mysite2/') is a valid call even in grails 1.3.x, unfortunately there's no base parameter in that version to perform the redirect i was suggesting you. I guess upgrading to grails 2 is not an option, is it?

Comment: Upgrading is currently not a option :(